# Typescript not working in vue SFC

Tags: laravel, typescript, webpack, vue.js

Well, after spending literally all day and 10 hours trying to get up and running with typescript, I'm at a loss why this isn't working.

NOTES:
- using Laravel and webpack, fresh install, nothing fancy that would have broken any of the 50+ guides I've looked at in setting this up
- all normal .ts files compile, but I cannot use  in my vue components.

Webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.ts', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.webpackConfig({
    devtool: mix.inProduction() ? '' : 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.vue', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        alias: {
            styles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/sass'),
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/assets/js'),
        },
    },
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strict": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "target": "es2015",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "resources/assets/js/*"
            ]
        }
    },

    "include": [
        "resources/assets/js/**/*.ts",
        "resources/assets/js/**/*.vue"
    ],

    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

sfc.d.ts file:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
    import Vue from 'vue'
    export default Vue
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'll continue looking around but I feel as though I've exhausted most of the routes I can take.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) or something similar to be able to write single-file components(SFCs) in the first place.

This sfc.d.ts should be renamed to a vue.shims.d.ts or index.d.ts where type definitions are held. You don't need to import this file anywhere. Typescript will use it this whenever it encounters a `.vue` file
Now you can create an SFC with `lang` attribute set to `ts`.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
```

Here is a [Microsoft Doc](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-vue-starter#single-file-components) that explains the same. In our project, I have defined it as index.d.ts.